# How to work with NMEA protocol on Android API 21?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, nmea

I updated targetSdk and compileSdk to 29 version, but after updating version and libraries project not compile.

The LocationManager class no longer has the "addNmeaListener" and "removeNmeaListener" methods for android version 23 and lower.
These methods available after android version 24 and higher. I have minSdkVersion 21 for my project and I need NMEA protocol functionality on Android API 21.

Maybe, you have a resolution for me? How to work with NMEA protocol on Android API 21 with android10?

Comment: No solution: Star this issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134611316), sit comfortably and hope.